# How do I tell cucumber to execute feature files taking into consideration both feature tags as well the scenarios tags?

Tags: java, cucumber

Here is my problem.
I have a @env tag on feature level to identify which env to run on, and @current tag on scenario level to identify its the one to be run.

Feature files are placed under different folders (depending on the env) and I have used @Cucumberoptions to set the tag specific feature file path.

All good till here.

But when I run the feature files, it picks up all the scenarios with the @current tag irrespective of the feature file tag.
For E.G. I had added only @Env1 and @Env2 in the cucumber options, but it picks up @Env3 features as well and runs them. How do I stop cucumber to run feature files not mentioned in the @cucumberOptions?

Here is the ANT target code:

`<java classname="cucumber.api.cli.Main" fork="true" failonerror="false" resultproperty="cucumber.exitstatus">
            <sysproperty key="log4j.configuration" value="file:///${basedir}/log4j.conf"/>
            <classpath refid="classpath"/>

            <arg value="--monochrome"/>
            <arg value="--format"/>
            <arg value="junit:target/cucumber-junit-report/allcukes.xml"/>
            <arg value="--format"/>
            <arg value="pretty"/>
            <arg value="--format"/>
            <arg value="html:target/cucumber-html-report"/>
            <arg value="--glue"/>
            <arg value="src.test.cucumber.userlevel"/>
            <arg value="features"/>
            <arg value="--tags" />
            <arg value="@current"/>
            <arg value="--tags" />
            <arg value="~@obsolete" />
            <arg value="--tags" />
            <arg value="~@business" />

        </java>`

Any responses would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Need to use a AND, OR combination in the tag filter expression to make this work. Not too sure about how to run Cucumber from Ant so including tag filters in cucumberoptions and from cli.

**For cucumberoptions** -> `tags={"@Env1,@Env2","@Current"}`

**For CLI** -> `--tags @Env1,@Env2 --tags @Current`

**For Ant** ->

```
<arg value="--tags" />
<arg value="@Env1,@Env2"/>
<arg value="--tags" />
<arg value="@Current" />
```

Comment: Depending on which version of Cucumber you are using, you can use [Tag Expressions](https://docs.cucumber.io/cucumber/api/#tag-expressions), so you would use "and" to add a set of tags, rather than comma-separated.